# Event attendance, emote and list bot help needed. discord.js

Tags: events

im still new to the coding world and the last thing i want to enter into my bot is leaving me banging my head on my desk. im looking to create a embeded event with emotes that lists out how many and lists the name of everyone who clicked each emote.

https://sourceb.in/slb43pE4j0

i would like the value to post (# of memeber who chose the emote / 100) and to list who chose the emote underneath.

Comment: Right. So what’s your question…? Stack Overflow is for getting answers to _specific_ programming problems; not asking “How do I do X?”-type questions. Take the [tour](/tour) to learn what questions are acceptable here.

Comment: well i guess i was asking a how do i question, ive looked all over stack as well as discordjs documents. and found no help.  

my question is what do i have to do to get the value to showcase a list of people who chose each emote. 

but if that question isnt acceptable ill search else where i apologize